# Is it Possible to use a Single Certificate for a site which has many different domains

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, ssl, azure

I have an ASP.NET application on IIS(Windows Azure) which has many different domains. All domains are working on http. Now, I need to use https. Whether, a single certificate is fine for all of my domains which point a single ASP.NET application on Azure or I need a certificate for each my domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

The key point is that you can only assign a single certificate per Input Endpoint for Windows Azure service deployment. That said, you must have a single certificate for all the domains you want to serve. The way to achieve that is to use Subject Alternate Name (or SAN) Certificate.

Here is a (non-complete) list of some SAN SSL providers:

- [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/ssl/buy-ssl-certificates/specialized-ssl-certificates/san-ssl-certificates/)
- [ClickSSL](http://www.clickssl.com/ssl-certificate/san-ssl-certificates)
- [DigiCert](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/wildcard-san-names.htm)

**UPDATE** based on the comments

> Is it mean that, if I have abc.cloudapp.net which is pointed by
>   abc.com, abc1.com, abc2.com then only 1 certificate is enough

Yes, however this one certificate will be [SAN certificate](http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm) (please follow that link and read more about SAN Certs) and will have all that domains in its SAN (Subject Alternate Name) property. That certificate is typically more expensive that the regular SSL Certs.

> Is there is any legal issue of using a single certificate for many
>   domains? Whether CA will allow this?

NO. There is no issue. That is the purpose of [SAN Certificates](http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm). Please follow the provided links and read more about SAN Certificates.

Comment: Is it mean that, if I have abc.cloudapp.net which is pointed by abc.com, abc1.com, abc2.com then only 1 certificate is enough

Comment: Is there is any legal issue of using a single certificate for many domains? Whether CA will allow this?

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: Last Question. Is there is limit on number of domains? For example, this links says that you have no more than 49 domains, http://www.verisign.com/ssl/buy-ssl-certificates/specialized-ssl-certificates/san-ssl-certificates/. Is there is any option of 1 ssl with unlimited domains which is pointing my single website?

Comment: Either you are asking the wrong question, or the architecture you have is very strange. I've never seen app to run on more than 2-3 different DOMANs. If you are talking about SUBDOMAINS, it is different story. You may have a WILDCARD certificate for particular domain, so that: sub1.abc.com, sub2.abc.com, sub3.abc.com stc, all are supported by a regular SSL certificate. Anyway, this question is now far from Azure specific, and in an area where I am not expert. You may want to either post another question, specific for the SSL, or try searching the Internet for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can secure a different domains using single server SSL certificate. In order to secure multiple domains using single server certificate, that certificate must SAN SSL, which allows up to 100 multiple domain SSL security on single one.

Below enlisted are the list of the most trusted SAN SSL certificate provider, but at low price:

-> verisign -> rapidsslonline -> digicert